# Using sys.stdout.write() in Python instead of print

Tags: python-2.7, printing

How can i use `sys.stdout.write()` to accomplish what the `print` statement does below -

```
coeff = [6, 1, 0]
print "The coefficients a, b & c are: ", coeff

>>>The coefficients a, b & c are : [6, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
sys.stdout.write('The coefficients a, b & c are : ' + str(coeff) + "\n")
```

works fine.